# Find the lower limit of integrationt to solve probability density function?

Tags: probability

**Problem:**
The probability density function for the net weight in pounds of a packaged chemical herbicide is f(x) = 2.0 for 49.75 < x < 50.25 pounds

How much chemical is contained in 90% of all packages.

**My approach:**

$0.9=\int_a^{50.25}\ 2dx$

$0.9=2x\Biggr|_{a}^{50.25}$

$0.9=F(50.25)-F(a)$

$0.9=2(50.25)-2a$

$a=\frac{0.9-100.5}{-2}=\frac{-99.6}{-2}=49.8$

**What is the correct answer to this problem, and how do you get there?**

My answer (49.8) was marked wrong.  I'm not sure where I went wrong, or what the right answer is.

I thought I was right, since I checked my work by plugging in my solution and solving the integral $\int_{49.8}^{50.25}\ 2dx$, which gave me 0.9.  So, thought I was good. Where did I go wrong?

I found [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2856437/the-probability-density-function-of-the-net-weight-in-pounds-of-a-packaged-chemi) - but the accepted answer doesn't explain how to solve the problem.

Would appreciate some help in walking me through how you go about solving this one.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may depend on how you interpret "How much chemical is contained in 90% of all packages." Is that "Up to how much" or "At least how much"?

The distribution of $X$ is $\mathsf{Unif}(49.75, 50.25).$ Its density function is a rectangle. My interpretation is that you want the left-hand sub-rectangle that contains 90% of the area of the whole rectangle. Put that way, this is a grade-school geometry problem, not a calculus problem.

In R:

```
qunif(.1, 49.75, 50.25)  
[1] 49.8                 # 10th quantile
qunif(.9, 49.75, 50.25)
[1] 50.2                 # 90th quantile
```

[image]

Comment: Bruce, thanks for the help!  That makes sense to me. Should have drawn it out. Always helps to draw it out.

Comment: Still, I think it's an ambiguously worded problem. I think a large proportion of readers might have given your answer. Were you told the "officially correct" answer?

Comment: No. That's why I posted up here, I wanted to understand how to get the right answer. I think what you presented makes more sense to me based on how it's written.